# What is a more effective and efficient way to check for matching attributes and fields

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following model that has these fields:

```
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [IsSearchable]
        public string Code{ get; set; }

        [IsSearchable]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [IsSearchable]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [IsSearchable]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }  
        
        [IsFilterable]
        public int? Setting{ get; set; }

        [IsFilterable, IsSortable]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
```

I am writing a method to compare whether values in a database match this model. So far it looks like this:

```
 private bool CompareEquality(Index resultBody, Type indexType)
        {
            var properties = indexType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            List<PropertyInfo> searchableProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
            List<PropertyInfo> filterableProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
            List<PropertyInfo> sortableProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            if (properties.Count() == resultBody.Fields.Count)
            {
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    var isSearchableAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<IsSearchableAttribute>();
                    var isFilterableAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<IsFilterableAttribute>();
                    var isSortableAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<IsSortableAttribute>();

                    if (isSearchableAttribute != null)
                    {
                        searchableProperties.Add(property); 
                    }
                    if (isFilterableAttribute != null)
                    {
                        filterableProperties.Add(property);
                    }
                    if (isSortableAttribute != null)
                    {
                        sortableProperties.Add(property);
                    }
                }
                CheckAttributeEquality(searchableProperties, filterableProperties, sortableProperties);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The CheckAttributeEquality method:

```
 private bool CheckAttributeEquality(List<PropertyInfo> searchableProperties, List<PropertyInfo> filterableProperties, List<PropertyInfo> sortableProperties)
        {
            if (searchableProperties.Count == 4 && filterableProperties.Count == 2 && sortableProperties.Count == 1)
            {
                CheckPropertyFields(searchableProperties, filterableProperties, sortableProperties);
                return true; 
            }
            return false;
        }
```

As I started to write a method to check that the field names match, like so:

```
            foreach (var property in searchableProperties)
            {
                if (property.Name == "Id" ||)
                {
                    ...
                }
                if (property.Name == "Code")
                {
                    ...
                }
                // etc
```

I realised how messy and long-winded this whole approach is. I am not hugely experienced in C# and would appreciate any advice as to how I can refactor this up a little bit? I want to check for attribute and name matches.

Comment: If you are willing to share all of your code, and want a review of all aspects of the code, you should visit [the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) of [codereview.se] to see if your question is on-topic there. Refactoring code is an awfully broad subject for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Typedescriptor (`using System.ComponentModel`) for that. Try this:

```
var pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this ); //or your model object, if its not "this"
foreach (var property in searchableProperties)
{
   var descriptors = pdc[ property.Name ];
   // check if your searchable descriptor is there, and do error handling
}
```

Once it works, you could also try to solve it with LINQ.

Comment: there is no `import` in .NET